# Magento 2 default suffix

Tags: magento2, url

I see Magento hasn't changed the default of the suffix in Magento 2 so my question is really why does Magento default to .html? I know you can change it but there must be a reason why its still a default. It just seems weird as modern websites don't have .html suffixes

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, out of the box only the category and product pages have a default suffix .html declared in `Magento\Catalog\etc\config.xml` :

```
<seo>
    <product_url_suffix>.html</product_url_suffix>
    <category_url_suffix>.html</category_url_suffix>
</seo>
```